# How to match strings within two columns in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have two tables with the following information.
Table A

```
desc                 amt
SHELL ZA EXPLOR    47267.49
SHELL ZA EXPLOR    4637957
```

Table B

```
desc                          amt
DUMMYPayments_Shell Pet.     47267.49
Olufemi Oduneye              4637957
```

i Want a script that matches table A to B like this based on the amount and pattern in the description field:
Output:

```
desc               desc                     Amount      Amount
SHELL NG EXPLOR   DUMMYPayments_Shell Pet   47267.49    47267.49
```

Comment: What are the rules of the pattern?

Comment: Amount is a very bad column to join on. Please consider using unique keys instead. Also your tables does not match the expected output you provided.
In your output  you should get two rows and the data in the output doesn't match the data provided. It's confusing

Comment: that's just bad data, sanitise it before trying to do anything meaningful. From this example alone, you an see how inaccurate any future queries are going to be.

Comment: The output is matching based on the fact that the key word "SHELL" is in the description column of the two tables. Am also aware that joining on the "amount" will produce duplicates, that why i need to narrow the match down using the description columns by pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below

```
SELECT A.[desc]
      ,B.[desc]
      ,A.amt 
      ,B.amt 
FROM @TableA A
    INNER JOIN @TableB B
    ON A.amt=B.amt
```

Result

```
desc               desc                     Amount      Amount
------------------------------------------------------------------
SHELL NG EXPLOR   DUMMYPayments_Shell Pet   47267.49    47267.49
```

Comment: Clearly works in this simple example.  However, you run the risk of duplicate values across instruments.

Comment: you're not considering the desc field, which the OP specifically asked for.

Comment: The output is matching based on the fact that the key word "SHELL" is in the description column of the two tables. Am also aware that joining on the "amount" will produce duplicates, that why i need to narrow the match down using the description columns by pattern matching.